# How to Add Date Field type in Drupal 7

Tags: date, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-fields

I was wondering how to add a date field type in drupal 7. I was following a video tutorial, when I notice that I dont have a "date" field type in my select options. How will i do that?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a date module at https://www.drupal.org/project/date. Once, you enable this module there will be a date field type.